# A Question About Tennebaum's Theorem?

Tags: logic, model-theory, computability, peano-axioms

[Tennenbaum's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem) proves there are no countable recursive [nonstandard models of Peano arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-standard_model_of_arithmetic). It is a proof by contradiction. If our countable, nonstandard model is recursive, then, given a pair of recursively inseparable sets, $A$, $B$, we can construct a separating set, $C$, such that $A \subset C$ and $C \cap B = \emptyset$. This would mean $A$ and $B$ are recursively separable contradicting our assumptions.

The separating set, $C$, can be a nonstandard finite set. For example, $C$ could the the exponents of the binary expansion of some non-standard natural number. Because we are assuming the non-standard model is countable, there are only a countable number of definable (in the model) nonstandard finite sets.

We didn't make any assumptions about the recursively inseparable sets so I can choose any such pair. If there are an uncountable number of pairs of recursively inseparable sets how can a countable non-standard model only have a countable number of separating sets? If the separating set, $C$, is not definable in the non-standard model then how does Tennenbaum derive a contradiction?

Another way to state my question is: are there sets of standard natural numbers such that these sets are not a subset of any definable nonstandard set in a countable non-standard model of PA?

Comment: I told you before about humility in your titles. You should **always** start with the working assumption that there is nothing wrong in the established knowledge, and that you are wrong. If you dare make such claim that there is a flaw then you shouldn't pose it as a question. You should pose it as a proof, and even then if you want it to be treated seriously by mathematicians it is better to suggest the possibility of mistake, not to make it as a bold claim like you post here.

Comment: And as the previous questions that you posted showed, it is the usual case that **you** didn't understand very delicate points (which are difficult to understand, that is true). So please. Each time you give such silly titles to your question you erode a little more whatever patience people will have for you. And that's a shame, because I truly admire the fact that you try to prove the inconsistency of arithmetic *while playing by the rules*, and not by claiming that it has to be the case for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

To the question at the end of your post, no. There are no such sets. Every set of standard integers is a subset of $\{x\mid x=x\}$ of every model of $\sf PA$.

Comment: Thanks. I should have seen that. It does come down to separability. Is there always a nonstandard separating set?

Comment: I suppose that you mean *recursive* set? I don't know. In any case, note that if $C$ separates $A$ and $B$ then it separates every subset of $A$ from every subset of $B$. So every separating set is separating uncountably many pairs of sets on its own.

Comment: All finite sets are recursive in the model. The separating set can always be reduced to a non-standard finite set. I think we can show there must be an uncountable number of separating sets. There are an uncountable number of nonrecursive standard sets that are not subsets of $A$.